# Need advice which template is better?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, usability

I posted here recently looking to improve a template in hopes to increase engagement with the page and decrease bounce rate.

Here is an example of a page how it used to look before:

http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem_dev.php?problem_id=213

Here is what it looks like now thanks to the advice on people here:

http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=213

Here is what I changed:

```
1) problem text has white background
2) Social bookmarks and voting moved to the right so it doesn't distract from main content
3) I aligned the grid lines to be more consistent throughout the page. (does it show?)
```

Which one looks better the problem_dev.php link? Or the problem.php ?

Also, what other improvements should I make? I am sure many things are still not perfect with the page.  Any suggestions what to improve next?

Also, one question: on the right side divs, the headings for them, should they be centered or left-adjusted?

Comment: You still didn't implement one of the main suggestions: show proposed solutions in full.

Comment: @dnbrv the reason I didn't do it is that I am still wondering if it might to a good way to get people engaged with the site.. might do it soon at some point...not sure.

Comment: Also, I am getting mixed feedback on whether I should present all the content at once, or get people engaged with it bit by bit and discover features, etc.  So not too certain how to best handle it.

Comment: You should post screen shots of the different layouts as well to avoid link rot and so users don't have to use external URLs.

Comment: Hi Genadinik, please make your question more specific - right now you're asking for general critique, which is something this site isn't meant for. Try editing your question to ask something specifically about UI or UX and less a matter of a person's opinion on which is better.

Comment: @Rahul ok makes sense - in the future will try to be more specific :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"problem_dev" is better, not because it looks better, but because the points of interaction are better grouped.

Voting up and down, when moved into the sidebar will be easy to ignore entirely, when I assume it's something you really want to promote.

In addition, I recommend using fewer boxes, allowing more white space.
Move 'email friends' to the sidebar, reserve main column for core functionality.

Comment: well, you see, I was thinking that the more important interaction would be to comment, or suggest problem solutions. Tats why I moved the voting to the side.

Comment: If this site is supposed to be something like StackExchange sites, then what even more important than gathering answers is providing _relevant_ answers. The cream needs to rise to the top. There's no shame in starting with what works and tweaking it.